# cannot convert 'listNode**' to 'listNode*' in assignment

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have an error when  create a simple linked list.
The error message is `cannot convert 'listNode**' to 'listNode*' in assignment`.

**The code:**

```
struct listNode {
    const char *data;
    listNode *link;
};


int main(){
    listNode *node = new listNode;
    node->data = "Adley";
    node->link = NULL;

    listNode *node2 = new listNode;
    node2->data = "Bert";
    node2->link = NULL;

    listNode *node3 = new listNode;
    node3->data = "Colin";
    node3->link = NULL;

    node->link = &node2;
    node2->link = &node3;

    for(listNode *i = &node; i != NULL; i = i->link){
        std::cout << i->data << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I know that this question is easy to solve it, but I'm sorry my brain is confused now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change:**

```
node->link = &node2;
node2->link = &node3;
```

**To:**

```
node->link = node2;
node2->link = node3;
```

Remove the ampersands(&). `node2` and `node3` are already pointers. No need to point to pointers :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for(listNode *i = node; i != NULL; i = i->link){
    std::cout << i->data << std::endl;
}
```

you must use  `*i=node` NOT `*i=&node` in the init-expression of the `for` 
the type of `i` : `listNode*` 
the type of `node` : `listNode*` 
but the type of `&node` : `listNode**`